# Why is sed putting substituted text at the start of a line?

Tags: bash, sed

On Mac OS X (bash), I'm using the following sed at the command line:

```
$ sed 's/\(\S*\)/\1 ~ /' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

`file1.txt` has lines like these:

```
some/path_to/somewhere/-     some{"stuff here"}-and_etc
some/path_to/somewhere.else-     some.more{"stuff here"}-and_etc
```

So I expect that a ~ will appear where spaces begin after the first set of non-space characters. Instead, I get this in `file2.txt`:

```
 ~ some/path_to/somewhere/-     some{"stuff here"}-and_etc
 ~ some/path_to/somewhere.else-     some.more{"stuff here"}-and_etc
```

I've tried adding `^` ahead of the `\(\S` but that makes no difference.

How can I get `file2.txt` to look like this:

```
some/path_to/somewhere/-~     some{"stuff here"}-and_etc
some/path_to/somewhere.else-~     some.more{"stuff here"}-and_etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure your sed does not understand `\S` to mean "non-whitespace". It's most likely trying to match "zero or more `S` characters", and it finds that match at the beginning of the string.

You want to stick to the POSIX character classes:

```
sed 's/[^[:blank:]]\+/& ~ /' file1.txt
```

Comment: BSD (Mac OS X) `sed` does not understand `\S` by default.  In fact, even with the `-E` option to enable extended regular expressions, it doesn't understand `\S` as non-space.  On Mac, to use the `+`, you need to use the `-E` option.

Comment: ... or install GNU sed from `macports` :) and use it as `gsed`.

Comment: Ultimately `sed -E 's/([^[:blank:]]+)/& ~ /'` worked, so this answer and Jonathan Leffler's comment did it.